# tslint how to disable error "someVariable is declared but its value is never read"

Tags: tslint

I'm using tslint, and got the error.

```
'myVariable' is declared but its value is never read.
```

I went to the website that documents the rules https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ and searched for the string `is declared but its value is never read` but didn't find that text.  While I can and did look for settings that might be tied to this error, it shouldn't be a guessing game.

**What is the configuration change needed to suppress/stop this error?**

Just as importantly, **when I get an error in tslint that says "this happened" how can I find what setting is used to configure or change the tslint behavior on how to handle that error?**

I also did a search on the website (google search I used was)

```
site:palantir.github.io  is declared but its value is never read
```

but a direct hit did not appear, so the answer might be on the palantir.github.io website but I just didn't (yet) find it.

**How do others find the tslint variable/configuration settings that change to suppress a particular error?**

Please refrain from suggesting I comment out the code that is causing the problem.  I'm looking for an answer to my more general question as well as to the specific question.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting `noUnusedLocals` to `false` in your `compilerOptions` ? Recommended by this post: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19700#issuecomment-382469957

Comment: "noUnusedLocals" : false, + "noUnusedParameters": false, worked for me

Comment: This rule is like having to drive at 20mph with a Ferrari

Comment: as if you would like to have a ferrari with a bunch of loose / unused pieces in the engine :)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**Fist question:**

Edit the file: `tsconfig.json`, adding/modifying key `"noUnusedLocals": false` as follows.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  }
}
```

You'll need to restart the server.

**Second question:**

If it is a tslint error; **VS Code** shows, in the error message, the **rule** that's been applied.

> Identifier 'doc' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
> (prefer-const)

The `prefer-const` rule in this case.

Comment: Or you can apparently [declare variables you only use in the template `protected`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19700#issuecomment-348950146) rather than turning off checking for any unused locals.

Comment: Thank you! So many sources say this is just a tslint/eslint config, but the tsconfig was actually what I needed

Answer (score 155):

Any parameter name starting with `_` is exempt from the check. Use `_myVariable` instead of `myvariable` to remove this warning.

Comment: It does not happen automatically, you have to specify ignore pattern.

`"no-unused-variable": [true, {"ignore-pattern": "^_"}]`

 But yes, this is a good solution.

Comment: I didn't have to specify that pattern, worked for me right away

Comment: As an update, `"no-unused-variable"` is deprecated since TypeScript 2.9 https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4046

Comment: Worth noting that since tslint is deprecated, you should use eslint and typescript-eslint instead.  Using _ does not automatically bypass that rule no-unused-vars, but requires configuration like Rachit said.   https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.  Using _ still does bypass the TS compiler automatically.

Comment: The current preferred way to implement this (to the best of my knowledge) is, in your `.eslintrc.js` file:
` '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error', { 
      'argsIgnorePattern': '^_'
    }],`
use `argsIgnorePattern` if referring to arguments in something like a decorator, and/or `varsIgnorePattern` to ignore declared variables.

Answer (score 47):

Add this line just before the line which causes the error:

```js
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
```

You will no longer receive the tslint error message.

This is a better solution than turning off the error for you whole codebase in tslint.conf because then it wouldn't catch variables that really aren't used.

Comment: But what would be the command to disable next line with eslint?

Comment: Raphael: see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars

Answer (score 43):

## New solution

First, turn off `noUnusedLocals` in tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
  }
}
```

Then fix eslint rules in `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error', { 'varsIgnorePattern': '^_', "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
  },
};
```

And If using `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule should add `leadingUnderscore: 'allow'`, For example, if you are using Airbnb config:

```
'@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
  'error',
  {
    selector: 'variable',
    format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase', 'UPPER_CASE'],
    leadingUnderscore: 'allow',
  },
  {
    selector: 'function',
    format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase'],
  },
  {
    selector: 'typeLike',
    format: ['PascalCase'],
  },
],
```

**Note:** you should update all related `eslint` packages in package.json to the latest version manually.

Comment: Why hadn't it worked for me? I've put noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters to false in tsconfig.json. But VSCode still shows the ts(6133) error alongside the eslint warning in the popup window on hover. I'm using nuxt with takeover mode

Comment: @Seangle I have the same issue: Search for `unused` in your VS Code settings and turn it off. Personally, I like it on there, so I'm trying to figure out a way to only turn it off for a single line.

Answer (score 18):

Extend the tsconfig.json with dev.tsconfig.json

And run the command tsc -p ./dev.tsconfig.json

This will disable the unused variable and unused parameter in development

Inside dev.tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was the noUnusedParameters that was screwing me over

Comment: If you are using defaut vite + electron quick start. Add these compiler options to ```tsconfig.node.json``` and ```tsconfig.web.json```

Answer (score 5):

I am using `typescript": "2.9.1"` with `tslint": "^5.10.0`.

I was getting tons of error such as

```
Property 'logger' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Also, I observed that I was getting a warning when running `ng-lint`

```
$> ng lint
no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
```

So, I removed the `no-unused-variable` rule fromt `tslint.json` - and that seems to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons you could be getting this error/warning:

1. Your `tsconfig.json` needs to default/disable `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters`.
2. Your .eslintrc.json needs to set `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["off"],`.
3. (And I haven't seen this one mentioned yet:) Your VSCode setting named `"editor.showUnused"` may be set to true. It overwrites these tsconfig.json and .eslintrc.json settings, at least in my workspace.

You can find this setting by searching for "unused":

[image]

For me, I actually want this warning most of the time* but not always. Unfortunately, none of the comment hints seem to work on this vscode setting. The only workarounds/hack I've found is to put an `export` in front of it or remove all the other `export`s in the file.

* Maybe that's a good reason to turn it on everywhere, something I'll try later.

Answer (score 3):

There are two type of variables and you can do it in two ways

1. argsIgnorePattern
2. varsIgnorePattern

   - `no-unused-vars: ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]`
   - `no-unused-vars: ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]`

Both these rule in eslint will ignore any function arguments and variables that starts with _ sign respectively

Answer (score 1):

I saw a solution on this web site: https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/angular-form-ngform-and-two-ways-data-binding.

it helped me but only 50% of it

**This is my modified code:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';// i added this line and one more line.
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DheerajComponent } from './dheeraj/dheeraj.component'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DheerajComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    FormsModule, // this one. remaining all default code
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **react** if you have some thing like this

```
export default class Body extends Component {
    
    let data = null; // somethings like this line

    // ...
    // ...
```

convert it to

```
export default class Body extends Component {
    
    data = null; // somethings like this line

    // ...
    // ...
```

Comment: Just remove `let` or `const` or `var`

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to disable it just for a moment, when developing, the best way may be to just run the `tsc` compiler with an additional command line flag:

```
$npx tsc -w --noUnusedLocals false --noUnusedParameters false
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to avoid this is to create a get-method for every variable you have, like this:

```
get variablename():variabletype{return this.variablename;}
```

Comment: This adds potentially unnecessary code to fix a linter warning. Much better to actually configure the linter to your liking than to add unused code.

Comment: This is no unnecessary code if you work with classes with private properties.