# How to disable the TS6133 “XXXXX is declared but its value is never used” warning in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode version 1.52 and would like to disable the `TS6133 “XXXXX is declared but its value is never used”` warning.

I did a search and some people suggested turning off the `noUnusedLocals` in `tsconfig.json`, but I could not find that file.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565671/ignore-ts6133-import-is-declared-but-never-used) to that question.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could not find a `tsconfig.json` file because you never created one? I assume the warning is a default warning. If you have no `tsconfig.json` yet, you can create one, and then configure it to your needs.

Comment: Please let me know where to host this file.

Comment: You should put the `tsconfig.json` in the root directory of your project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tslint how to disable error "someVariable is declared but its value is never read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011443/tslint-how-to-disable-error-somevariable-is-declared-but-its-value-is-never-rea)

Answer (score 0):

Update the tsconfig.json.

```
/* Linting */
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false, // make sure this is false to have no errors
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
```